# Smart edit time restriction requires refresh

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am having issues with OOTB Smart Edit time restrictions. When we apply time restriction from let's say 1st of March till 5th of March and the in the preview select 6th of March the page doesn't reflect the change. It will require a hard refresh.

Looking at CMS web services ending on "/cmsitems/uuids" we can see the correct from and until time.

Occasionally we get this error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Undefined]
    at resolvePromise (vendor_chunk.js:formatted:59045)
    at vendor_chunk.js:formatted:58983
    at vendor_chunk.js:formatted:58994
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (vendor_chunk.js:formatted:58715)
    at Zone.run (vendor_chunk.js:formatted:58524)
    at vendor_chunk.js:formatted:59091
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (vendor_chunk.js:formatted:58738)
    at Zone.runTask (vendor_chunk.js:formatted:58566)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (vendor_chunk.js:formatted:58862)
```

Have you experience the same issue?

Thanks

Comment: What specific Hybris version (including minor version) are you using? Have you also considered updating to the latest patch?

Comment: Hi @geffchang I am on 1905.12, and yes I did try updating to the latest patch. It seems that BE is returning the correct data. If I open the preview link in incognito it works. If I open in same session on new tab it is showing old content.

Comment: Maybe it's a known issue. I've had cases when visibility/access of users in SmartEdit is not correct, especially when I login using different users (for testing). What I'll do is clear cache the browser before logging in the user.

Comment: I am also facing similar issue in Hybris 1811. Did you guys have any solution ?